# open xml, set cellvalue html string

Tags: c#, openxml

Technologies: C#, openxml
I am trying to create xlsx file using opennxml document. Data table contains one column with rich text in html string. example "**hi**" or **hi**
How to append/set value to cellValue.Text. Please suggest any other approach to achieve this.

```
          Cell cell = new Cell() { CellReference =                           ExcelHelper.ColumnCaption.Instance.Get((Convert.ToInt32((UInt32)rowIndex) - 2), cIndex), DataType = CellValues.InlineString };

          cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);

         CellValue cellValue = new CellValue();                        
         cellValue.Text = data.Rows[rIndex][cIndex].ToString();//<b>hi</b>
         cell.Append(cellValue);
```

Comment: this could be any html string link, provided "<b> for example.